# Plinq inside Plinq?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, parallel-processing, plinq

Let's say I have a `DataTable`.

```
var dt = getDataTable();
```

and then I do

```
Parallel.For (0, dt.Rows.Count, i => Foo (dt.Rows[i]));
```

`Foo` is a function which  do some calculations  on a `row`.

Should Foo **also** use `Plinq` ? or Should not ?

*( it doesn't make sense to divide into cores after already divided.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should Foo also use Plinq ? or Should not ?

In general, you typically only want to parallelize at the "highest level" possible.  By making larger work items, you maximize the total throughput, since you're reducing the amount of overhead required to schedule the work.

If you used PLINQ inside of a `Parallel.For` loop, you'd be adding overhead (in order to schedule the work items), but not being able to take advantage of more cores, so you'll likely reduce your overall performance.  As such, I would not recommend using PLINQ inside of `Foo` in this case (provided the `DataTable` has enough rows to parallelize nicely).

Comment: Hi @Reed. So how should I know which part to put in parallel  ? the `For` loop or the `Foo` work ? what is the criteria ? more rows at DT or more intensive cpu at FOO ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Typically, you want the "outer most" level, as this will make the largest individual work items.  Your outer loop, in this case, would be the for loop, so that's where I'd parallelize.